# Need help in calculation using two Datasets using Expression SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I am creating an SSRS report where

> In Dataset15, I have value Jan - 100 & Feb - 110
>
> in Dataset16, I have value Jan - 80 & Feb - 100

Now I want to calculate same thing in a line chart using expression - `Jan - 80/100` which should be 80% & `Feb - 100/110 - 91%`

When I am trying to find out individual monthly number 100, 110 I am getting 210  which is the summation of Both - `Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "DataSet15")`.

Kindly help me out how can I get individual Numbers.

Answer (score 10):

You would need to restrict your dataset to the desired month and then sum the results.

**LookupSet** is used to retrieve data from another dataset based on criteria.

A VBA function, SumLookup is needed to add the results from the LookUp. This VB would go into the CODE section of the report (this can be seen under 'Report Properties').

```
Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal

If items Is Nothing Then Return Nothing

Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()
Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()

suma = 0
ct = 0

For Each item As Object In items

  suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
  ct += 1

Next

If (ct = 0) Then return 0 else return suma 

End Function
```

You would then use the function in your expression like:

```
=Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!MONTH.Value, Fields!MONTH.Value, Fields!Total.Value,"Dataset16"))
```

If your field is a date, then you'd need to convert both to a MMyyyy field with FORMAT:

```
FORMAT(Fields!MONTH.Value, "MMyyyy")
```