# SSRS Timeline Report from two different datasets

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

2008 SSRS

Hi, I am trying to make a timeline chart using two different datasets in my report. My first PERMIT NO works and counts perfectly. However, when I use my second PERMIT NO from the second dataset, it will sum them for each day. It should be showing 2 on 7/16, 1 on 7/17, and 0 for the rest of the month. But as you can see, for some reason it puts 3 for each day and I'm not sure why. Here is my expression being used:

> Count(Fields!PERMIT_NO.Value, "DataSet2")

How would I go about fixing this? I tried sum, countdistinct, etc. but nothing worked properly.

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkxD9.png)

[Chart Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvOsD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your count is getting the count of all PERMIT_NOs in DataSet2. The COUNT doesn't filter by your date.

You'll need to use a **LOOKUPSET** to get the data and then a VBA function like **SUMLookup** to SUM them.

Here's an answer that's similar to yours. Since you want a COUNT, use the number 1 to SUM instead of your PERMIT_NO field.

[Need help in calculation using two Datasets using Expression SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131860/need-help-in-calculation-using-two-datasets-using-expression-ssrs/)