# SSRS - How to Sum values on a LookUpSet expression

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Hi I have a column that uses a lookupset expression `=Join(LookupSet(Fields!ReportUNC.Value, Fields!ReportUNC.Value, Format(Fields!cntSelfService.Value, "###,#######0"), "ExecutionCount"))`.I'm getting an incorrect parameter when I sum that expression to `=Join(Sum(LookupSet(Fields!ReportUNC.Value, Fields!ReportUNC.Value, Format(Fields!cntSelfService.Value, "###,#######0")), "ExecutionCount"))`. The column to sum is cntSelfService. Please advise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a few different issues with your expression.

1. When you use the **FORMAT** function, the result is a string, not a
   number.
2. **JOIN** is used to concatenate strings from a table into a
   single string which wouldn't help your issue.
3. **SUM** will not work with a LookupSet

Unfortunately, there's not a built-in way to sum values from a LookupSet.

Luckily, users have had this issue for a while and someone created a function in Visual BASIC **SumLookUp** that will add the values from a lookupset. You add the code in the **Report** Properties --> Code tab.

Your expression would be:

```
=CODE.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!ReportUNC.Value, Fields!ReportUNC.Value, Fields!cntSelfService.Value, "ExecutionCount"))
```

See the code in: [Need help in calculation using two Datasets using Expression SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131860/need-help-in-calculation-using-two-datasets-using-expression-ssrs/36143175#36143175)