# SSRS Calculation between different tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

Two separate tables by month.  I need to use the monthly amount from table 1 with the monthly total in table 2 for a frequency calculation.

This expression retrieves the last months total from table1.
=(SUM(Fields!ClaimCount.Value) / SUM(Fields!InsCnt.Value,"ds_Table1"))

Is there a way to calculate this and match the months for each table?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eehh6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEYfP.png)

Answer (score 0):

As each textbox is static in your tables then each will have its own name.

Click the cells you want to do hte calculation on and get their names from the properties window (e.g. the one you have selected in you screen shot is "TextBox14"). Once you know the names of the cells you can use the ReportItems collection.

```
=(ReportItems!TextBoxB17.Value / ReportItems!TextBoxB8.Value)
```

Comment: Thanks I've tried that.  The report item from the top table is the December total.  I'm trying to match the month.  January amount from table 1 divided into January total from table 2.  The calc above takes January total from table 2 divided by December total in table 1.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that the months are in a column group. You may have to use a LOOKUP or LOOKUPSET to get the values from the top table

Comment: Yes I need to use a LOOKUPSET.  Also had to use the following function.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131860/need-help-in-calculation-using-two-datasets-using-expression-ssrs/36143175#36143175