# SSRS LookupSet - Join() works but Count() does not

Tags: reporting-services

This works:

```
=IIf(
    Fields!EntityID.Value Is Nothing,
    Fields!Foo.Value,
    Join(
        LookupSet(
            Fields!EntityID.Value,
            Fields!EntityID.Value,
            Fields!Bar.Value,
            "dsMain"
        )
    , ",")
)
```

But this doesn't:

```
=IIf(
    Fields!EntityID.Value Is Nothing,
    Fields!Foo.Value,
    Count(
        LookupSet(
            Fields!EntityID.Value,
            Fields!EntityID.Value,
            Fields!Bar.Value,
            "dsMain"
        )
    )
)
```

I get #Error, like if the formula is broken. What's wrong with it?

Comment: The syntax is correct but the LookupSet doesn't produce the table array that COUNT is expecting. The `.Length` looks easier but I've used VB for SUMming. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131860/need-help-in-calculation-using-two-datasets-using-expression-ssrs/

Comment: @HannoverFist I don't know why, but the LookupSet result doesn't have a .Length property, at least for me. Intellisense doesn't suggest it, and it is underlined in red as incorrect syntax.

Comment: If you want to try the VB solution you can use the above link and just change the `suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)` line to `suma += 1` to change it from summing to Counting. You might need to change the type of your column `(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal`. Maybe change the function name from SumLookup to CountLookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Length property of an array to get the element count

```
=IIf(
    Fields!EntityId.Value Is Nothing,
    Fields!Foo.Value,
        LookupSet(
            Fields!EntityId.Value,
            Fields!EntityId.Value,
            Fields!Bar.Value,
            "dsMain"
        ).Length
)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had already seen that suggested in other threads, but at least for me, intellisense doesn't show a .Length property for my LookupSet, and it is underlined in red as syntax error when I type it in.

Comment: I don't know why you have intellisense issues. Sure thing is that it works, I can provide screenshots.

Comment: You are right. It does work even with the error indication and intellisense not working. Thank you.