# Sum Lookup field from a different dataset

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have 2 datasets that I need to populate one table.  Dataset 1 contains values that Dataset 2 may not contain.  Dataset 2 contains multiple values that I need to get the Sum of.  Dataset 2 will always have a matching value (Division_Code) that is contained in Dataset 1.

I need the full list of data from DataSet1, even if no data exists in Dataset2.

Dataset 1 fields:
Division_Code,
Long_Name

Dataset 2 fields:
Division_Code,
TotalBillable,
Date

i.e. Dataset 1:

| Division_Code | Long_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | Health |
| 02 | Safety |
| 03 | Finance |
| 04 | Tax |

i.e. Dataset 2:

| Division_Code | TotalBillable | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | $200 | 06/01/2022 |
| 01 | $100 | 06/08/2022 |
| 01 | $200 | 06/12/2022 |
| 02 | $800 | 06/01/2022 |
| 04 | $100 | 06/05/2022 |

I need results like this:

| Division_Code | Long_Name | Sum(TotalBillable) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Health | $500 |
| 02 | Safety | $800 |
| 03 | Finance | 0 |
| 04 | Tax | $100 |

I have tried a variety of Lookups and SumLookup expressions and all result in errors.  Can anyone offer guidance on how to write an expression that would accomplish what I need? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming tat you cannot do this directly in your dataset queries (by far the easiest way) then take a look at this blog post https://salvoz.com/posts/2013-05-27-sum-result-of-ssrs-lookupset-function.html

Comment: If you're using a SumLookup like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131860/need-help-in-calculation-using-two-datasets-using-expression-ssrs/36143175#36143175 , you're expression would be `=Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!Division_Code.Value, Fields!Division_Code.Value, Fields!TotalBillable.Value,"Dataset2"))`. Your TotalBillable isn't a text field with the dollar sign, is it?

Comment: @AlanSchofield I haven't figured out a way to do it directly in my dataset because dataset2 does not contain the complete list of division_code fields since not all division_codes have billable amounts.  I need the list of division_codes in its entirety, regardless if data exists in our billing tables

Comment: @HannoverFist this is what I tried initially.  The TotalBillable is an INT field with no dollar sign (I'll just format the cell that way).  When I use this expression though, I get an error for the TotalBillable field "Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope"

Comment: The error seems to indicate that a field or dataset name is incorrect. Are you sure they are all correct?

Comment: From your earlier comment, you said dataset2 does not have a complete set of divisions. To get around this, how about you drive your query from division I.E. select div.code, div.name, isnull(sum(billing.amount),0) bil_total from division div left join billing  on div.code = billing.div_code  group by div.code, div.name

This way, you are always guaranteed all divisions all the time

Answer (score 0):

**Use this Custom Code in Report Builder Properties:**

```
Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal  
If items Is Nothing Then  
Return Nothing  
End If  
Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()  
Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()  
suma = 0      ct = 0  
For Each item As Object In items  
suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)  
ct += 1  
Next  
If (ct = 0) Then return 0 else return suma   
End Function
```

**Then use the following expression in your report field**

=Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!**[LookupDataset1FieldName]**.Value, Fields!**[LookupDataset2FieldName]**.Value, Fields!**[ResultField]**.Value, "DataSet2"))